# How to set different dimensions in a codemirror editor?

Tags: javascript, php, codemirror, ui-codemirror

I need each codemirror editor with different dimensions in a php page.

Like below we can create an instances of codemirror editor but it should have same dimensions.Is there any way to create different dimensions?

```
function editor(id)
{
    CodeMirror.fromTextArea(id, {
        height: "350px",
        parserfile: "parsexml.js",
        stylesheet: "css/xmlcolors.css",
        path: "js/",
        continuousScanning: 500,
        lineNumbers: true
    });
} 
editor('code1');
editor('code2');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, add your dimensions in additional parameters in your editor function.

For example :

```
function editor(id, h)
{
    CodeMirror.fromTextArea(id, {
        height: h,
        parserfile: "parsexml.js",
        stylesheet: "css/xmlcolors.css",
        path: "js/",
        continuousScanning: 500,
        lineNumbers: true
    });
} 
editor('code1', '350px');
editor('code2', '450px');
```